# Alignment in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I've got the alignment issue that shows in IE, this is the page:

http://calibredesign.com/clients/spec/index.html?view=http://calibredesign.com/clients/spec/envi_news.html

there's a big gap between the picture and the copy at the first paragraph, Does anybody know how to write css code to minimize the gap?

Thanks for your help!!

Comment: Give your own `padding` and `margin` for `<p>`.

Comment: There is actually a `<font size="2px">` in that paragraph. May not be the issue, but it shouldn't be there at all. Not only is the font tag really archaic, but also 2px isn't even a valid value for its size attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The content of your TD elements seems to be floating left when it doesn't need to be. I think that's probably causing the IE issue.

You really shouldn't be using TABLE elments to layout your page unless it's actual tabular data.